# SQL query to join columns in result

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm a complete SQL noob and have no idea how to utilize JOINs. If someone could help with this query, it would be great.

I have a table `questions` which contains two columns: `queid` and `que`.
Another table `options`, contains the corresponding options for the questions, and has columns `optionid`, `queid`,`option`.

How can I do a `SELECT` statement such that I can join both tables together based on `queid` ?

Something like:

```
SELECT * from questions,options where queid=1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try this:

```
SELECT que.*, opt.* FROM questions que
INNER JOIN options opt ON que.queid = opt.queid
WHERE que.queid = 1
```

`INNER JOIN` loads questions and options having at least one corresponing record in every table.

If you need to get all questions (even the ones not having options) you could use

```
SELECT que.*, opt.* FROM questions que
LEFT JOIN options opt ON que.queid = opt.queid
WHERE que.queid = 1
```

`LEFT JOIN` always loads questions and, if they have options, their options too; if not you get NULL for options columns.

Comment: I get a `ambiguous column queid in where clause` message.

Comment: @xbonez: maybe you were reading my answer while I was editing it. Try it now

Answer (score 2):

May be by

```
SELECT * FROM questions q JOIN options o ON q.queid=o.queid WHERE q.queid=1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT q.*,o.* FROM questions q 
JOIN options o ON  q.queid = o.queid
WHERE q.queid = 1
```

Comment: it should be `q.queid = o.queid`.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM questions
JOIN options ON questions.queid = options.queid
WHERE questions.queid = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can join two related tables using the column that they have in common.

in your case you can write :

```
SELECT * FROM Questions as Q INNER JOIN Options O ON Q.queid=O.queid WHERE Q.quid=1
```

You can also omit the where part like this :

```
 SELECT * FROM Questions as Q INNER JOIN Options O ON Q.queid=O.queid AND Q.quid=1
```

There are different kind of joins :

INNER

OUTER(Left,Right,Full)

By inner join you mean that only records that are common in both tables are returned
When you use outer join all the records on the given side are return plus the records that have corresponding values on the other side otherwise instead of the other side values you will get null.